# Docker host's FQDN resolves to 127.0.1.1 inside user-defined network

Tags: docker

I have Docker running on a machine that has an externally resolvable FQDN (i.e. `example.com`). The machine has it's hostname set to `example.com` and has an entry in `/etc/hosts` like:

```
127.0.1.1 example.com
```

When attached to a user-defined network, queries for the FQDN resolve to `127.0.1.1`, which incorrectly directs my application's requests to the container instead of the host.

```sh
$ docker network create test && docker run -it --network='test' debian:10 
root@db7770f7e8dd:/# apt update && apt install -y dnsutils && dig example.com
<... omitted apt logs ...>

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u6-Debian <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6032
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            0       IN      A       127.0.1.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 01 05:39:20 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Repeating the test with the `/etc/hosts` entry removed yields the correct result.

Running the container on the default `bridge` network (`docker run -it debian:10`) also yields the correct result (`/etc/resolve.conf` does not use [Docker’s embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services)).

How can I correctly resolve the host machine's FQDN from inside the networked container without simply removing the entry from `/etc/hosts` on the host machine?

Comment: Ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: I did not. I settled for using the host's IP address.

Comment: I was able to use the `hostname` parameter in my docker compose, and then reference the containers by name.